# Summing product of two arrays of different sizes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm interested in visualizing a loglikelihood function of two variables.

Here is a little code to do that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate fake data
x = np.random.normal(0,1,size = 100)
y = 2*x+1 + np.random.normal(size = x.size)

#Create a grid to visualize the log-likelihood
grid = np.linspace(-5,5,101)
B0,B1 = np.meshgrid(grid,grid)

#Compute the log likelihood
LogLik = 0
for xs,ys in zip(x,y):
    LogLik+= norm.logpdf(ys, loc = B0+B1*xs)

plt.contourf(B0,B1,LogLik)
```

The bottleneck in this little piece of code is the computation of the log likelihood, namely

```
for xs,ys in zip(x,y):
    LogLik+= norm.logpdf(ys, loc = B0+B1*xs)
```

If the length of x or y is very large, then this takes longer than I care for.  Is there a way to vectorize the creation of the mean of the distribution (i.e. the `B0+B1*xs`) as well as the evaluation of the `logpdf`?

Comment: Sorry I can't help with this, but I think the title of your post is quite different from the actual problem description. You might want to check that, to maximize your chances of getting a good answer. Good luck !

Comment: execution of this code took `Wall time: 55.8 ms`. What's your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be vectorized easily by broadcasting newaxis to the arrays. As a result, the bottleneck `norm.logpdf` will be executed only once:

```
log_lh = norm.logpdf(y, loc=B0[..., None] + B1[..., None] * x[None, None, :]).sum(axis=2)

# comparison with LogLik:
np.allclose(LogLik, log_lh)
# Out: True
```

Refactoring this into a function will allow to time the executions:

```
def loglik(x, y, B0, B1):
    return norm.logpdf(y, loc=B0[..., None] + B1[..., None] * x[None, None, :]).sum(axis=2)

def loglik_loop(x, y, B0, B1):
    LogLik = 0
    for xs, ys in zip(x, y):
        LogLik+= norm.logpdf(ys, loc=B0+B1*xs)

%timeit loglik(x, y, B0, B1)
# Out: 94.1 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit loglik_loop(x, y, B0, B1)
# Out: 54 ms ± 4.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As you can see, this seems to be one of the rare cases, where vectorizing the code **does not improve the performance**. There seems to be another bottleneck within the `norm` module of scipy, which hampers the performance when operating on multi-dimensional arrays.

As a result, your only possibility to improve the performance of your code will be to implement a parallel execution of the loop (replacing the `+=` operator with assigning to a fixed array and summing afterwards).

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about array broadcasting but couldn't remember that is what it was called. Interesting to see that vectorization hinders performance.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for the upvote even though I did not improve the performance of your code. This might be an interesting question on scipy github. Perhaps they can tell you how to speed up the code and/or find the bottleneck within the `norm` module.